# Latent classes and relabelling

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova

Suppose, I take the MINST dataset which contains images for 0-9 digits and I have a magical feature vector that allows to classify them almost perfectly.

Now if I relabel the dataset to have binary classes; say odd and even numbers and try to build a classifier it will also work. Because the original classes are well separated and no matter how I group them, the groups can be predicted.

This (release of a relabelled dataset) can lead to an only partially correct conclusion that one can predict odd/evenness of numbers using the images. Partially correct in the sense that odd/evenness can be correctly predicted because the actual underline pattern is the uniqueness of the numbers than there are group level unique properties for odd an even numbers.

There can be scenarios where this is not even partially true.

What is the statistical technique to detect such properties in a dataset? From ML domain, some cluster analysis might help.

Comment: I followed you here half way through but then I lost your argument. Can you rephrase why it is only partially correct? And what if the "this" you hope to detect in the last apragraph?

Comment: Revised to add more details.